# Overlay with centered/vertically aligned message

Tags: html, css, overlay, vertical-alignment

I would like to make an overlay on my site to prevent user from clicking somewhere. It's sometimes very handy. In the middle of the overlay I want to place a message like "please wait.." or "loading...".

I've made a `div`, which covers the whole screen and a span inside of it, which contains the message. I managed to center the `span` inside the `div` horizontally, but I'm struggling with the vertical alignment of it. The message should be also vertically centered.

Here is my code so far:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="overlay">
    <span>Please wait...</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#overlay span {
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexxus/kaJSs/).

So, how do I get the span with the message vertically centered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LIke this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kaJSs/1/)**

add below select in `position:relative` or `top:50%;`

**CSS**

```
#overlay span {
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
}
```

Comment: I've already tried the `top: 50%;` on the `span` but forgot the `position: relative;`. Doh! :-) Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I know, but I couldn't. You have to wait 5 minutes before accepting an answer :-/

Answer (score 0):

Besides that if the Center object is bigger in **height & width**, you can give negative margins exactly half of the same.

```
  #overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;enter code here
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#overlay span {
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-50px;
    margin-top:-50px;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Theoretically you are right, but a `span` is an inline element. You can't set dimensions on it

Comment: yes, i just meant 'just in case' there is an inner element with bigger height & width - then it is the solution

Comment: But your code will not work. You have to correct it. You can't set `width` or `height` on a span element.

Comment: yes just by adding 'display:block' I can make a 'inline element' look like 'block level' element